# generalization and aggregrates, entities

Tags: domain-driven-design

Hello I have 2 entities that share some properties in common, studying and teacher, and then I thought about making a generalization

[image]

but I was in doubt as to how I can represent this in my domain.
should i have the person table as a normal entity? or as a root aggreggrete?
or wouldn't you need to represent that person entity and just the two students or teacher entities as aggregrate root ?

I have doubts about how to model my domain in a situation of generalization.
But specifically I have doubts as to whether I should put my person class as aggregrate root and everything that is in common between the entities is in the person class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some misunderstanding about DDD here. An aggregate root should never reference an other aggregate root direcly. The only way for an aggregate root to reference an other is with its ID. I'm not talking about a foreign key here. Keep in mind that each aggregates could be in a separate database. So sharing properties between aggregate roots is strongly discouraged.

The first thing you should do is establish your bounded contexts. Maybe students and teachers are from two differents bounded contexts or maybe they should be spitted in multiples entites. Keep in mind that its ok to duplicate data across bounded contexts.

Comment: Oops good night, the reference I speak is with the id.
I believe they are in the same context:

the student answers questionnaires, and participates in teachers' classes.

teachers teach classes and apply tests

Comment: I believe it is just a context, my question was how to model it, would it be following a common class diagram?

the person entity, would it be an aggregrate root?

Since students and teachers have similar data

Comment: In a purist implementation each aggregate root can run in its own process and be written in a different language so no you cannot have a base class between "teacher" and "student" if you consider them as aggregate roots. Again its ok to duplicate data across bounded contexts.

Comment: so can i duplicate the data in the limited context and keep my generalization in my relational model?

Comment: my relational db*

Comment: Why would you do that? Persisted aggregates should be isolated too. Database normalization doesn't fit well in DDD.

Comment: I think you got me wrong, I don't talk about my persistence, but rather the modeling of my tables, in other words, I can have a generalization, and in my domain I only have student, and teacher .

Comment: "I don't talk about my persistence, but rather the modeling of my tables" then youre talking about reading data? The way you read your data should not impact your design. You should take a look about CQRS. You can't think about doing DDD right without CQRS.

Comment: *'An aggregate root should never reference an other aggregate root direcly'* This is quite a dogmatic statement to make. Vaughn Vernon uses this as a *best practice* in his book "Implementing Domain Driven Design", but that doesn't make it universally true. The blue book by Eric Evans says "*Objects within the Aggregate can hold references to other Aggregate roots.*" and at QCon 2009 Evans said "There was an over-emphasis on access rules within aggregates .... A much more useful view at aggregates is to look at them as consistency boundaries for transactions".

Comment: "Objects within the Aggregate can hold references to other Aggregate roots." of course but by ID not a full in-memory reference. Thats what I meant by "not directly".